# Detect Exchange version by Redemption

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-redemption

does anybody know how to detect Exchange server version when connected by Redemption?

rdoSession.ExchangeMailboxServerName  returns the machine name
rdoSession.ExchangeMailboxServerVersion  returns something like "14.3.181.4006"

what I need to find out is whether its 2007 or 2010, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enough information to determine the exact version of Exchange you are connected to. The *ExchangeMailboxServerVersion* is returning the build number of the server you are connecting to, and you can compare this number to a list of server versions. For example, I know that the build number you reference is **Update Rollup 5 for Exchange Server 2010 SP3**.

For a list of the build numbers, product names, and release dates check out this article on TechNet:

[Exchange Server Build Numbers and Release Dates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098.aspx)

I hope this helps. If this does resolve your question, please mark this post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---

Answer (score 1):

Check out this site:

> [Microsoft Exchange Server Version List](http://exchangeserverversions.blogspot.com/)

It contains a list of all Exchange Server *versions*, *service packs* and *update rollups* and which four-part version number those refer to.